# How can I find out why MATLAB crashes?

Tags: windows-7, crash, matlab

I'm using MATLAB GUI code that handles ten files, uses the image acquisition tool extensively, and also the data acquisition tool, and GPU programming.

It usually works well, but from time to time (more often lately) MATLAB completely crashes, and I need to restart it.

The system uses Win7-64 (ultimate) SP1, and has a Xeon CP E5-1650 @3.2 GhZ with 64GB RAM, and a Tesla C2075 GPU. The matlab version is 2012a, and it also uses the latest GPU Acceleration on MATLAB with Jacket.

When Matlab crashes Win7  offers to "debug", and the visual studio Just-In-Time debugger informs that "An unhandled win32 exception occured in the Matlab.exe [2176]"

After this happen just restarting Matlab doesn't work (the symbol is showing, but then it vanishes and nothing happen), and I need to reboot.

Why is that, and how could I detect it? I could only think of a memory leak, or defective memory.

**UPDATE:**
Matlab also started to crash on me for simple guis that worked before. Now matlab won't load at all, I get the logo screen for a split second and then nothing happens. Win 7 Check memory and chkdsk didn't help. I installed an updated Java versiom, that didn't help either... Next, I'll try reinstalling Matlab :(

**UPDATE 2**

I tracked the problem to be, believe it or not, the camera software that was written as an adapter for Matlab (in Java). I learned from the company (Allied vision) that the java code they were using was conflicting with Matlab on the OS level, and since then they had released a new version of software that is stable (called Vimba). The camera (Prosilica GX) is working with Matlab but only with about half the frame rate it should (~60 fps instead of 112 fps). Both TMW and Allied vision know about this and I have yet to get a solution from them (over almost a year now).

Comment: Hi nate! Knowing at least your operating system and version of MATLAB would help.

Comment: So sorry, absolutely right (too late for me here) I'll update relevant details...

Comment: Just to confirm: After you `clear` the workspace and run a specific code fragment usually does not crash but sometimes it does? In this case, could you describe what the code is doing and how much memory it takes? Have not tried this solution, but calling `pack` now and then may be interesting.

Comment: Correct, on small codes it works well, something in the big code makes it crash, the problem is that I can't debug it using matlab debugger (as explained in the question).

Comment: Given your update I would say the problem is at least partially related to your computer. You may want to start out clean again.

Comment: I assume that by now you have found the solution or at least a workaround. If you would share it the question does not remain unanswered. Otherwise try to log some more things whilst you are running the code (memory usage, input sizes?).

Comment: see my latest update...

Comment: @bla could you post your answer as an answer and mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

I tracked the problem to be, believe it or not, the camera software that was written as an adapter for Matlab (in Java). I learned from the company (Allied vision) that the java code they were using was conflicting with Matlab on the OS level, and since then they had released a new version of software that is stable (called Vimba). The camera (Prosilica GX) is working with Matlab but only with about half the frame rate it should (~60 fps instead of 112 fps). Both TMW and Allied vision know about this and I have yet to get a solution from them (over almost a year now). I have decided not to continue with Allied vision because of that...

Comment: 4 years after the original question? That's dedication

Comment: was asked to yesterday, why not?